# Adjusted R square for each predictor variable in python

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, p-value, pearson-correlation

I have a pandas data frame that contains several columns. I need to perform a multivariate linear regression. Before doing that i would like to analyze the R,R2,adjusted R2 and p value of each independent variable with respect to the dependent variable.
For the R and R2 I have no problem, since i can calculate the R matrix and the select only the dependent variable and then see the R coefficient between it and all the independent variables. Then i can square these values to obtain the R2.
My problem is how to do the same with the adjusted R2 and the p value
At the end what i want to obtain is somenthing like that:

```
 Variable     R        R2       ADJUSTED_R2   p_value
 A            0.4193   0.1758   ...
 B            0.2620   0.0686   ...
 C            0.2535   0.0643   ...
```

All the values are with respect to the dependent variable let's say Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will not give you ALL the answers, but it WILL get you going using python, pandas and statsmodels for regression analyses.

---

Given a dataframe like this...

```
# Imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

# A datafrane with random numbers
np.random.seed(123)
rows = 12
listVars= ['y','x1', 'x2', 'x3']
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2017', periods=rows, freq='D')
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,150,size=(rows, len(listVars))), columns=listVars) 
df_1 = df_1.set_index(rng)

print(df_1)
```

[image]

...you can get any regression results using the statsmodels library and altering the `result = model.rsquared` part in the snippet below:

```
x = df_1['x1']
x = sm.add_constant(x)
model = sm.OLS(df_1['y'], x).fit()    
result = model.rsquared
print(result)
```

[image]

Now you have r-squared. Use `model.pvalues` for the p-value. And use `dir(model)`to have closer look at other model results (there is more in the output than what you can see below):

[image]

Now, this should get you going to obtain your desired results.
To get desired results for ALL combinations of variables / columns, the question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624071/run-regression-analysis-on-multiple-subsets-of-pandas-columns-efficiently) should get you very far.

**Edit:** You can have a closer look at some common regression results using `model.summary()`. Using that together with `dir(model)` you can see that not ALL regression results are availabel the same way that pvalues are using `model.pvalues`. To get Durbin-Watson, for example, you'll have to use `durbinwatson = sm.stats.stattools.durbin_watson(model.fittedvalues, axis=0)`.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241482/get-durbin-watson-and-jarque-bera-statistics-from-ols-summary-in-python) has got more information on the issue.